# Reverse Shopping Script

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, shopping-cart, zen-cart, x-cart

I am trying to find a shopping Script where instead of buyer bidding , I want the seller to bid money on the wish list of a buyer .

Is there any script / Plugin like this  or would i have to build it from scratch ?

Answer (score 0):

For X-Cart - build from scratch or try to find something at http://marketplace.x-cart.com/addons-modules/